# Displaying permissions of a folder for all users and groups using C# Programatically

Tags: c#, permissions, directory

I am working on a requirement where i need to display the permissisons of a folder for all Users and Groups programatically using C#.

**Here, is the code, i am using to do it:**

```
 DirectorySecurity filesecure = Directory.GetAccessControl(txtPath.Text);

 StringBuilder strbldACLlist = new StringBuilder();

 filesecure.GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm(AccessControlSections.All);

 foreach (FileSystemAccessRule ace in filesecure.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
                {
                    strbldACLlist.Append(ace.FileSystemRights + ":" + ' ' + ace.IdentityReference.Value + "\n");
                }
```

**I am getting the output like this:**

```
"ReadAndExecute, Synchronize: dm1\\55555\nFullControl: dm1\\343556\n268435456: dm1\\343556\nFullControl: NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM\n268435456: NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM\nFullControl: BUILTIN\\Administrators\n268435456: BUILTIN\\Administrators\n"
```

Here, for the first user i am getting properly the file permissions. But, if you see the second userid i.e **343556** , i am getting result two times as you can see Full Control for first time nad some number **n268435456** which i do not under stand.

**Can any one please analyze the output and explain what's happening actually..**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/5211a077-63fc-4016-b750-25bf26b3ad15/why-does-getacl-return-filesystemrights-that-are-invalid-in-filesystemaccesrule-used-with-setacl?forum=winserverpowershell). It's saying that FileSystemAccessRights is a Flags enum (i.e. its values can be or-ed). The actual number you've got 268435456 - is a combination for which a name hasn't been supplied.

Cheers -